# Migrated questions listing bug

Tags: bug, migration

There is a bug when migrated questions are listed in SO:

[image]

as you can see, there's no OP nickname or something else. It's just empty space there. This is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286239/fastest-m0-thumb-32x32-64-function) of which I'm talking about.

Since inside question there is non-clickable OP nickname, I think it should present in questions list too.